# How to populate regime in Z-Score backtest?

Tags: python, finance, trading, back-testing

I am currently trying implement a single asset backtest, where buy signal is generated when zscore goes below a certain threshold and sell when it goes above the threshold.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('XBT.csv', index_col = 0)
df1 = df1.drop(['ADJUSTED','VOLUME'], axis = 1)
df1.head()

                        OPEN        HIGH         LOW       CLOSE
Date                
2016-09-25 22:00:00 600.1650    600.2850    599.3190    599.4575
2016-09-25 22:01:00 599.4550    600.1605    599.2980    599.5125
2016-09-25 22:02:00 599.5101    601.0850    599.2945    600.1450
2016-09-25 22:03:00 600.2950    600.6150    599.3290    599.3350
2016-09-25 22:04:00 599.3350    600.1400    599.3350    599.6972
```

Further I calculated rolling zscore, thresholds and cumulative return.

```
window = 300 #HYPERPARAMETER 5 hours lookback
df1['zScore'] = (df1['CLOSE']  - df1['CLOSE'] .rolling(60).mean())/df1['CLOSE'] .rolling(60).std()
df1 = df1.dropna()
entryZscore = 4 #HYPERPARMETER arbitrary naumber based on visual observations
exitZscore = 0 #HYPER PARAMETER
df1['cumret'] = df1['CLOSE'].divide(df1['CLOSE'].ix[0])


                        OPEN    HIGH         LOW        CLOSE    zScore cumret
Date                        
2016-09-25 22:59:00 599.8950    600.1239    599.5101    599.5376    -0.068662   1.000000
2016-09-25 23:00:00 599.5626    600.0743    599.5500    599.5775    0.001960    1.000067
2016-09-25 23:01:00 599.5750    600.0372    599.2800    599.9372    0.656922    1.000667
2016-09-25 23:02:00 600.3245    600.3245    598.5426    599.8000    0.416065    1.000438
2016-09-25 23:03:00 599.8000    599.9950    599.8000    599.9901    0.749235    1.000755
```

The problem for me is creating a Regime value that will indicate whether we are long(1), short(-1) or neutral(0) to later create strategy return values. I have attempted to do so by crating entry and exit points, but stuck from here on. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
df1['long entry'] = np.where((df1.zScore < - entryZscore) & ( df1.zScore.shift(1) > - entryZscore), 1, 0)
df1['long exit'] = np.where((df1.zScore > - exitZscore) & (df1.zScore.shift(1) < - exitZscore),1, 0) 
df1['short entry'] = np.where((df1.zScore >  entryZscore) & ( df1.zScore.shift(1) <  entryZscore),1, 0) 
df1['short exit'] = np.where((df1.zScore < exitZscore) & (df1.zScore.shift(1) > exitZscore),1, 0)
df1['close pct ch'] = df1['CLOSE'].pct_change()
df1 = df1.dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

To track your positions you need to implement the whole position management system. You ought use a platform that supports these things already so you actually focus on the trading algorithm.

I have seen a company distress research on Quantopian: 
https://www.quantopian.com/posts/campbell-hilscher-szilagyi-chs-model-probability-of-corporate-failure  The notebook might be outdated and not run anymore but the whole idea is there.